# Eclipselink static weaving in Java web application - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, ant, eclipselink

Im currently working on project where I develop Java web application. I use IDE Eclipse.

As data layer I use EclipseLink(2.6) JPA. Web application runs on Tomcat webserver(7). Now I realized that I need to use LAZY fetching for my Entities because of performance issues.

After some research I figured out that I need to use "static weaving", acording to manual pages, I found that I have 3 possibilities how to do that: Ant, Maven or use command line.

Since I have no experience with Ant, Maven or command line options I dont know how to continue now. I would like to pick easiest solution, which is Ant (from my begginer point of view). Can you suggest?

My project is divided into two projects:

- JPA project, with persistence entities and database operations
- Java application with servlets and JSP, this project contains link to JPA project

I run that application on:

- remote Tomcat server - then I generate .war file that contains both projects and then I upload it on server
- localhost - then I run that application directly from Eclipse (Run As -> localhost)

Can please somebody tell me process how I should continue now?

Shall I specify two steps Ant build that firstly create .jar from my JPA project, then do static weaving and continue in building web project to .war? So far I found only Ant builds where .jar applications are generated, not sure how it differ to web applications. Any tutorials there?

Can please somebody share some hits? I am complete beginer in this area - perhaps I missed some easy ways. My main goal is to have .war file that contains entities with static weaving, secondary goal is to automate deploying on tomcat localhost server, as I do it now from Eclipse IDE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for the Maven side of things, because thats the one I have experience with.

Inside your `pom.xml` , under `plugins` you will have to add the maven staticweave plugin:

```
<plugin>    
  <groupId>de.empulse.eclipselink</groupId>         
  <artifactId>staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>weave</goal>
            </goals>
        <configuration>             
           <persistenceXMLLocation>META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXMLLocation>>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>           
</plugin>
```

You may have to adjust your `persistence.xml`-location.

Inside your `persistence.xml` you will need to activate static weaving:

```
<properties>
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value = "static"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving.internal" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving.lazy" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving.changetracking" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving.eager" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
 </properties>
```

Again, you may have to change your platform, desired logging level and the other parameters. 
If you leave all the `eclipselink.weaving.*`-parameters out, they will have their default values.

The static weaving happens in the `process-classes` phase of the maven lifecycle after the compile phase. If you have packaging set to `war`, you will get a single `*.war`-file that you can then deploy.

If you would really rather do it via ant-task, you should look at 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving#Use_the_weave_Ant_Task

I can't really answer any questions about that though.